# Bitswallet core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Please does anyone know how to synchronise bitswallet with network. Have been trying to synchronise mine with network. But it does not seem to be synchronising with the network.

I need help fixing it. I think am not doing it right.

Comment: Why are you using bitswallet? I wouldn't trust software downloaded from a website that was only created a few months ago. I would choose a wallet from https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Comment: I have bitcoins in it already and it won't connect with the internet.

Comment: I suspect you have been cheated out of your money by criminals. How did you choose bitswallet core - did someone suggest them?

Comment: I thought it was the bitcoin core. What will happen to my coins. I thought it's possible to enable it connect to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use bitswallet for the following reasons

- I wouldn't trust software downloaded from a website that was only created a few months ago.
- I wouldn't trust a website that contains a lot of nonsense phrases
- I wouldn't trust a website whose contents seem to be almost identical  copies of other untrustworthy websites - bitswallet.net, bitwallet.at, and a bunch of Russian websites concerning Bitsblock core, Bitgo core and other similar names.
- I wouldn't trust a website that has no easily verifiable details of who runs it

Instead I would choose a wallet from bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Comment: Thanks. I'll be careful next time.